# Is this matrix in the coset of SL (2,R)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $SL(2,R)=[A \in GL(2,R); det(A)=1]$. Let $B=\begin{bmatrix}5&1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}$. Is $\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$ in the coset $B*SL(2,R)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coset $B\cdot SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is
$$
B\cdot SL(2,\mathbb{R})=\{M\in GL(2,\mathbb{R}):M=BA\text{ where }A\in SL(2,\mathbb{R})\}.
$$
Is it possible for $\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}=BA$ to be true?  Hint: Take the determinant of both sides.

Comment: But how do you find the determinate of BA when A is not a given matrix?

Comment: I think I understand, so $det AB=det A*det B=1*6=6$? So therefore, the matrix is not in the coset because the determinants are not equal.

Comment: Yes, that's how it goes.